# Pass the background image of a form to another through a button?

Tags: c#, image, button, background

How i can do what, the background image of a form1, be equal to the background image of a form2 through a button?

This is my button with the image in the form1 (Pressing this button change the background of form1.)

```
private void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._02_blue
}
```

I want what this image be the background image of the form2
Examples will serve me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I missing something?

```
form2.BackgroundImage = form1.BackgroundImage;
```

Where `form2` is instance of `Form2` and `form1` is instance of `form1`

Comment: And assuming you have more than one form, How do you think you could do it?

Comment: `form3.BackgroundImage = form2.BackgroundImage = form1.BackgroundImage;` Like this ?

Answer (score 1):

just use a  static property on  Form1 and retrieve it from form2

```
public  static Image Form1Background
 {
    get ; set;
 }
```

//to set in your Form1

```
 Form1Background= this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._02_blue;
```

// from others form

```
 form2.BackgroundImage=  Form1.Form1Background
```

Comment: Don't you feel this is unncecessary since we already have `Properties.Resources._02_blue` itself as a static property we could use that itself

Comment: ok but if you read the question you will  notice  that the image can change

Comment: So..? How will this handle that change?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to inject it into `Form2`. Build a new constructor:

```
public Form2(Image bg) { this.BackgroundImage = bg; }
```

and then use that when building it:

```
var f = new Form2(this.BackgroundImage);
```